# Youtube API Authentication C#

Tags: c#, youtube

I am using this method to **authenticate** and post comments to YouTube but it is not working, i want to know is it the right way to authenticate YouTube API 2.0 in C# ?

```
        YouTubeRequestSettings reqSettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Youtube Comments", devkey, "gmail address", "password");
```

May be i need to specify *client ID* but not sure where?

Comment: Have you see the docs? : http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r902/docs/folder56/M_Google_YouTube_YouTubeRequestSettings__ctor_2.htm

Comment: Checked it but that's old version i am using 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate requests using either **AuthSub** proxy authentication or **ClientLogin** username/password authentication.

To perform any operation using the YouTube API, you create a YouTubeRequestSettings object, which specifies the authentication information and authentication scheme to be used. With that object, you then create a YouTubeRequest object that you will use to actually perform the operations. (If you do not specify authentication information when creating the YouTubeRequestSettings object, then you will only be able to use the YouTubeRequest object to perform operations that do not require authentication.)

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = 
  new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", clientID, developerKey);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
```

The above example was taken from here, were you can see all de details about the **AuthSub** proxy authentication or **ClientLogin** authentication

**[https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet)**

To obtain a developer key and client ID visit 
**http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ Import Namespace="Google.GData.Client" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Google.GData.Extensions" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Google.GData.Calendar" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>

<script runat="server">
    void PrintCalendar() {

        GAuthSubRequestFactory authFactory = new GAuthSubRequestFactory("cl", "TesterApp");
        authFactory.Token = (String) Session["token"];
        CalendarService service = new CalendarService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
        service.RequestFactory = authFactory;

        EventQuery query = new EventQuery();

        query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

        try
        {
            EventFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
            foreach (Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry entry in calFeed.Entries)
            {
                Response.Write("Event: " + entry.Title.Text + "<br/>");
            }
        }
        catch (GDataRequestException gdre)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)gdre.Response;

            //bad auth token, clear session and refresh the page
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                Session.Clear();
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, true);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Error processing request: " + gdre.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Site</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1>AuthSub Sample Page</h1>
    <div>
    <%
        GotoAuthSubLink.Visible = false;

        if (Session["token"] != null)
        {
            PrintCalendar();
        }
        else if (Request.QueryString["token"] != null)
        {
            String token = Request.QueryString["token"];
            Session["token"] = AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(token, null).ToString();
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, true);
        }
        else //no auth data, print link
        {
            GotoAuthSubLink.Text = "Login to your Google Account";
            GotoAuthSubLink.Visible = true;
            GotoAuthSubLink.NavigateUrl = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(Request.Url.ToString(),
                "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/",false,true);
        }

     %>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="GotoAuthSubLink" runat="server"/>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Above example taken from

**https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/authsub_dotnet**

Comment: Saw it too but not working ClientID is deprecated may be but this Constructor is not present in YouTubeRequestSettings.

Comment: @AltamashShaikh did you check all the different kind of authentication methods that are shown under the **Authentication** section ?

Comment: Checked but a little confused with 'Token' and 'Secret Token' can you help me about it, from where i can get token and secret token?

Comment: @AltamashShaikh I just added a sample that shows how to do that

Comment: Well i am using Desktop Applications, but that too is helpful Thanks a lot mate .. :)

Comment: @MauricioGracia Good job! But this is just an example, I hope people don't start mixing markup and logic in the same page..

Comment: @Oscar as I mentioned the example was taken from the Google Developers page, and as usual people should adapt the code to meet their company standards/quality rules (like code behind, variable names, comments, etc)